# integrating a function in delphi for a very small intervals value

Tags: delphi

My problem is that i need to integrate a numerical function with a very small values for the interval of the integration.

I prefer to use delphi 10 and newer versions.

Comment: Can you give a specific example ?

Comment: integrating an exponential function in the range of: 0.000001   to 0.000008

Comment: That is trivial to solve. The integral of exp is exp. So your answer is `exp(.000008) - exp(.000001)`. Is there a problem evauating this?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to have a look at the [*Numerical Recipes*](http://numerical.recipes/) website (or a version of the book if you can find one). It provides algorithms (and code in a range of languages including Pascal) for carrying out numerical integration, plus a good discussion on the pros and cons of using particular algorithms.

Alternately, "an exponential function" may have an analytic solution, in which case you would not have to use numerical integration at all.